# Why are the non-fellow-students not referred to as guns in Clint Smith's "The Gun"?

Tags: poetry, wording-choice, clint-smith

This is sort of the reverse of my [previous question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/24474/why-are-all-the-schoolchildren-referred-to-as-guns-in-clint-smiths-the-gun) on Clint Smith's poem ["The Gun"](https://www.theatlantic.com/books/archive/2023/03/clint-smith-poem-the-gun/673542/). While it's blatant about referring to all of the kids as "guns", I find it interesting that the other characters aren't called as such.

At the very least they are given pronouns other than it/its. The shooter is "he":

> the gun heard *he’s down!*

The mother is "her":

> the gun hugged its sobbing mother    and cried into her arms

Recall that in addition to the main character being referred to over and over as a "gun", the other students are "guns" as well.

> the gun moved to a closet filled with several other shaking guns

Why are these other characters in the poem given human pronouns? What significance/meaning does that add to the poem?